# SAS: dim and macro variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
data example1;
    input var1 var2 var3;
    datalines;
    10 11 14
    3 5 8
    0 1 2
;

data example2;
    input var;
    datalines;
    1
    2
    8
;
```

Let's say that the number of *var* variables depending on data input. I want to put that number to macro variable and use in another data step, for example:

```
%macro m(input);

    data &input.;
        set &input.;

        array var_array[*] var:;

        %let array_dim = dim(var_array);

        do i = 1 to &array_dim;

            var_array[i] = var_array[i] + 1;

        end;

        drop i;

    run;

    data example2;
        set example2;

        var2 = var * &array_dim; /* doesn't work */

    run;

%mend;

%m(example1);
```

%let array_dim = dim(var_array); doesn't work in second data step, because dim(var_array) isn't evaluated, but %eval or %sysevalf in declaring the macro variable does't work here. How to do that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up macro code and data step code in a way that is not supported in SAS. If you want to assign a macro variable a value that you're generating as part of a data step, you need to use `call symput`.

Also, if you create a macro variable during a data step, you cannot resolve it during the same data step in the way that you are attempting to do (unless you use the `resolve` function...). It's easier just to use a data set variable for this.

So here's a fixed version of your code that I think probably does what you want:

```
%macro m(input);

    data &input.;
        set &input.;

        array var_array[*] var:;

        array_dim = dim(var_array);

        /*Only export the macro variable once, for the first row*/
        if _n_ = 1 then call symput('array_dim_mvar', array_dim);

        do i = 1 to array_dim;

            var_array[i] = var_array[i] + 1;

        end;

        drop i;

    run;

    data example2;
        set example2;

        var2 = var * &array_dim_mvar;

    run;

%mend;

%m(example1);
```